# The proof related to recursion in discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Fix positive integers a and b. Here’s an inductive definition of a set S:

Foundation rule: a,b∈S.
Constructor rule: If m,n∈S, then m−n∈S.

Suppose h is a common factor of a and b.  How to Use the exclusion rule to prove that for every n∈S,h divides n.

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: Isn't that a rule about illegally seized evidence and their inacceptence in court?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the exclusion rule is, but for any $m, n$ integer, if $h$ divides evenly both $m$ and $n$, then $h$ divides $m-n$ too. So recursively, starting from $a-b$ or $b-a$, every number implied by a constructor rule inherits the property of being divisible by $h$.

Answer (score 0):

With $S$ as given, define
$$ T=\{\,s\in S: h\mid s\,\}.$$
Then clearly $a,b\in T$ and $n,m\in T\implies n-m\in T$, in other words $S\subseteq T$..